# Google fonts not loading on android device in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-font-api

Google fonts is working perfectly when I use android studio emulator [image: emulator screensho]
But not working when I install the app on my android device[image: device screenshot]

Comment: make sure there is internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add **Internet Permission** in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 /// Add this line
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Then, rebuild apk again and try it in your device.
If it still doesn't work,
build **production apk** by running this command in terminal.

```
flutter build apk
```

Then copy `build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk` file and install it in your real device.

Hope it solves your problem. Cheers